# Xcode files disappeared from Mac

Tags: xcode

Mostly I am just sad I guess. Yesterday I finished an iPhone app in Xcode 10.2.1, loaded it onto my phone (it works nearly perfectly), and shut down Xcode. The app is on my phone and working, but when I opened the Xcode again the code (viewcontroller, AppDelegate, and storyboards) have no data. To be clear, the folders and files are still there, but the code/data is not. I did not have time back up the finished version. Is it possible to retrieve these from my phone? Or is there some other place to look to find it? Or am I stuck rewriting it (there are some iterations so it is not starting over completely, but it still sucks).
thanks

Comment: Are they only "invisible" to Xcode or do they exist on the file system?  I've been having issues with Xcode 10.2.1 on Catalina, where I add files to the project, but when I (clone and) open the project on another system running Mojave and Xcode 10.3 (recently), the files in the project appear, but can't be opened, so I need to remove them from the project (reference) and re-added them by dragging them in from the OS ... wasted a day on this 

Comment: I am not sure how to check if they are "invisible", but I think they simply do not exist. For example, if I open the ViewController.swift file in bbEdit, is see                  
        //  ViewController.swift
        //  GQv0.0
        //
        //  Created by dbrisson on 7/23/19.
        //  Copyright © 2019 dbrisson. All rights reserved.

        import UIKit

        class ViewController: UIViewController {

            override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
            }
        }

Comment: Sorry, not sure how to show that as code in a comment

Comment: Now that I look more closely, AppDelegate is still there. It is just the ViewController and the storyboards that are missing

Comment: Did you look in the actual project folder in the Finder at the actual project files?

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping - I figured it out. I duplicated then dragged the viewcontroller file from another project (a checkpoint save), thinking that meant the file moved. Turns out it did not move, the file stayed in the old project and was simply pointed to in the current project. At least that is my understanding. I guess that is not the best way to version control. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to retrieve these from my phone?

No, your phone contains only the compiled object code; it won't have any source code.

> Or is there some other place to look to find it?

It's hard to imagine how the code could have simply disappeared, so one would think it's probably there somewhere. I wouldn't think that you could compile an app without saving the code, and if you saved your work then it certainly shouldn't just be gone. If you can remember even just a part of a phrase from the missing file(s), you can search your machine for files containing it. Use Spotlight or even just `grep` for that.

If you're unable to recover the file(s), then rewrite it as soon as you can while it's still fresh in your mind. And use the experience as a lesson. In the future you should do both of the following:

- **back up regularly:** Use a backup system that works automatically. Apple's Time Machine works very well for this... all you need to do is plug in your backup disk and let the machine do it's thing.
- **use revision control:** There are a lot of options here, of course, but `git` is free and private Github accounts are also free, so you can save your work remotely. If you don't know how to use revision control, learn -- it's an essential development skill.